# Get value from online xml

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim, ultisnips

I want to get the value of the 'latest' version tag from here: https://papermc.io/repo/repository/maven-public/com/destroystokyo/paper/paper-api/maven-metadata.xml

I tried using this python:

```
import urllib.request
from xml.etree import ElementTree

opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]

data = opener.open('https://papermc.io/repo/repository/maven-public/com/destroystokyo/paper/paper-api/maven-metadata.xml').

root = ElementTree.fromstring(data)

versioning = root.find("versioning")
latest = versioning.find("latest")
snip.rv = latest.text
```

The problem is, using this inside of vim (I'm trying to make UltiSnips snippets with it) makes the whole of vim extremely slow *after* the code has finished running.

What's causing my program to slow down just when I add that ^^ code?

Comment: Will you be considering Pandas?

Comment: @pygo I don't think I have it atm, answer w/o is preferred but I can also install Pandas

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will solve the performance issue in vim, but the code was not running for me due to errors in it.

`opener.open` returns a file-like object, so you should read it using
`ElementTree.parse` instead of `ElementTree.fromstring` (actually there is a trailing dot after `opener.open(...)`, so I don't know if you missed a `read()` thereafter. In that case the return value is indeed a string).

Apart from that, you could try to close the `opener` to see if that frees up some resources (or use the `with`).

I attach an example of the improved code:

```
import urllib.request
from xml.etree import ElementTree

opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]

with opener.open('https://papermc.io/repo/repository/maven-public/com/destroystokyo/paper/paper-api/maven-metadata.xml') as data:
    root = ElementTree.parse(data)
    latest = root.find("./versioning/latest")
    snip.rv = latest.text
```